# A difficulty in understanding a solution .

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have question(1) in the following picture:

[image]

and the solution to it is given in the following picture:

[image]

but I do not understand why $||f^{'}||_{2}^{2} \geq \sum |(e^{inx}/\sqrt{2\pi},f^{`})|^{2}$

Could anyone explain this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [Bessel's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_inequality). A straightforward proof is given in the Wikipedia article, but it essentially hinges on
$$ 0 \le \left\| x - \sum_{k=1}^n \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k\right\|^2 = \|x\|^2 - 2 \sum_{k=1}^n |\langle x, e_k \rangle |^2 + \sum_{k=1}^n | \langle x, e_k \rangle |^2 = \|x\|^2 - \sum_{k=1}^n | \langle x, e_k \rangle |^2, $$
where $e_k$ are orthonormal. Taking $n \to \infty$ gives the general result.

Answer (score 1):

Let the space $S$ spanned by the given orthonormal set $V=\{v_n\}$, and $g$ be an element in $L^2$. Then $g=g_S+g_\perp$, where $g_S\in S$ and $g_\perp$ which can be obtained by the Gramm-Schmidt process. With some algebra with the inner product, we obtain 
$$\|g\|_2^2=\|g_S\|_2^2+\|g_\perp\|_2^2$$
and
$$\|g\|_2^2\ge\|g_S\|_2^2=\sum \big|(v_n,g)\big|^2,$$
where the last step could be deduced easily by the othornormality of $V$.